# Return hash key if hash includes value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash `hash` like so:

```
hash = {"Addaptive Accessibility"=>["one","two"],

        "Atmosphere (Feeling/Safety)"=>["three", "four"],

        "Aquatics (Size)"=>["five", "six"]}
```

I then have an array `array`:

`array = ["one","seven"]`

I need to search the hash for each word in my array, and if the word is found I need to return the associated `key` from the hash. Something like this:

```
array.each do |word|
  if hash.include? word
    puts key
  end
end
```

How can I write that, and write it better?

Comment: What if several keys contain the same value?

Comment: They won't, if you'll notice my hash all of the values are different. This is intentional and will remain consistent.

Comment: you're Hash is the wrong way around. The whole point of Hash is to use the key to look up the value. You need to rethink your data structure. eg hash={}; hash['one']=hash['two']='Adaptive Accessibility'; etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this ?

```
hash.select{ |_,v| v.any?{|e| array.include? e } }.keys
# => ["Addaptive Accessibility"]
hash.select{ |_,v| v.any?(&array.method(:include?)) }.keys
# => ["Addaptive Accessibility"]
```

Comment: @GarryVass I'm not oblivious to how the voting and answering system works here. I am however new to programming, and have realized that when I jump to conclusions and accept the very first answer I see I hinder myself by not allowing others to share different methods which may work better. I'm here to learn, and therefore will leave my questions open to others opinions.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your original question, I'll throw in another solution which I think is the easiest one to understand:

```
hash.find{|k,v| v.include? word }.first
```

This will only iterate until a match is found, i.e. you will probably save a few cycles. As opposed to @ArupRakshit's solution, this will however only find *the first* match.

I must however stress that you are indeed using the hash in the wrong direction – just flip keys and values around!

Comment: Variation of the same: `hash.find{ |k,v| break k if v.include? word }`

Answer (score 1):

```
hash.keys.select {|k| !(array & hash[k]).empty?}
```

- `array & hash[k]` is an array composed of the elements common to both `array` and `hash[k]`.
- we are only concerned with whether this 'intersection' is empty (`[]`).
- we could have used `(array & hash[k]).any?`, which is simpler, provided you never have keys  `false` or `nil`, since `[nil, false].any?` => false.